# Chat and Group chat application using Python

Tags: websocket, socket.io, xmpp, flask-socketio

In our python web application we need to implement a chat application (Single chat,Group Chat and File upload) , please suggest a better and stable solution .

Help is highly appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try matrix synapse: https://matrix.org/docs/projects/server/synapse

It also provides SDK: https://matrix.org/sdks/